# The Longterm motivation of Diablo 3

Tags: diablo-iii

Today I hit 60 with my first character and asked myself what is next on the list. I worry that the game won't keep me satisfied for much longer than a few weeks. Do you guys have the same problem and how can you solve it when you don't want to get all achievements?

Comment: Hardcore mode. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly some elements like max level gems and the Inferno difficulty are meant as time sinks to help motivate you for improving your character.

Ultimately what will probably provide the motivation for this relentless number grinding will be the introduction of the PvP arena.

PvP was a huge part of Diablo 2's long term success and I know from experience on other forums that the D3 arena is highly anticipated.